# I can't pass the input value from html to views

Tags: javascript, python, json, django

I am trying to create a add to cart function using Django but unfortunately i am receiving an error "POST http://localhost:8000/update_item/ 500 (Internal Server Error)" Please help.
Thanks in advance

views.py

```
def updateItem(request):

data = json.loads(request.body)
productId = data['productId']
action = data['action']
print('action:', action)
print('productId:', productId)
customer = request.user.customer
product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

if action == 'add':
    orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
elif action == 'remove':
    orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)
if action == 'add-cart':
    input_value = int(request.GET['quantity'])
    orderItem.quantity = input_value
orderItem.save()

if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
    orderItem.delete()

return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

Js code:

```
function updateUserOrder(productId, action){

console.log('User is logged in, sending data...')
var url = '/update_item/'
fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
        'Content-Type':'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    },
    body:JSON.stringify({'productId': productId, 'action': action})
})
.then((response) =>{
    return response.json()
})

.then((data) =>{
    console.log('data', data)
    location.reload()
})
```

}

Comment: You're going to have to go through there step by step and debug your code. It looks like there are too many places where your server could be throwing an error to be able to diagnose from here. You could try wrapping the function calls in try except blocks to get more descriptive errors.

Answer (score 0):

Error 500 means something went wrong with your python code, set debug=True in settings and take a look at logs to see which line is causing the error, with your code the error can happen because:

- you are accessing a wrong value in dict using []
- objects.get method is raising error because nothing is found
- objects.get_or_create is returning more than one item

as I said the solution is to check console logs and use print statements to see what is going on with your code.